# Inconsistency with lambda trailing return types

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, decltype, trailing-return-type

Consider [this](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Cexperimental/type_traits%3E%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3C+typename+Callable,+typename...+Args+%3E%0Ausing+ResultOfT+%3D+std::result_of_t%3CCallable(Args...)%3E%3B%0A++%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++auto+lambda1+%3D+%5B%5D(auto%26%26+id)+-%3E+decltype(id+%3D%3D+10)+%7B+return+id+%3D%3D+10%3B+%7D%3B%0A++auto+lambda2+%3D+%5B%5D(auto%26%26+id)+-%3E+decltype(auto)+++++%7B+return+id+%3D%3D+10%3B+%7D%3B%0A++%0A++static_assert(!!std::experimental::is_detected_v%3CResultOfT,decltype(lambda1),std::string%3E)%3B%0A++//static_assert(!!std::experimental::is_detected_v%3CResultOfT,decltype(lambda2),std::string%3E)%3B%0A++//+This+doesn!'t+even+compile!!%3F%0A++auto+bb+%3D+std::experimental::is_detected_v%3CResultOfT,decltype(lambda2),std::string%3E%3B%0A++%0A++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g7snapshot,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B1z+-O3'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7+(snapshot)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) code with gcc-7.0.0 latest snapshot:

```
auto lambda1 = [](auto&& id) -> decltype(id == 10) { return id == 10; };
auto lambda2 = [](auto&& id) -> decltype(auto)     { return id == 10; };

static_assert(!std::experimental::is_detected_v<ResultOfT,decltype(lambda1),std::string>);
//static_assert(!std::experimental::is_detected_v<ResultOfT,decltype(lambda2),std::string>);
// This doesn't even compile!?
auto bb = std::experimental::is_detected_v<ResultOfT,decltype(lambda2),std::string>;
```

where `ResultOfT` is just a wrapper over `std::result_of`.

Why `lambda1` and `lambda2` are not equivalent in this sense?

Per my understanding `decltype(auto)` at `lambda2` should be just the short form of `decltype(id == 10)`, but in fact it isn't, so what is the reason?

Is this a bug in GCC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard [says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function):

> Function templates can use return type deduction. The deduction takes
>   place at instantiation even if the expression in the return statement
>   is not dependent. **This instantiation is not in an immediate context
>   for the purposes of SFINAE.**

So there is no bug in GCC, it follows the standard and `lambda1` is **NOT** equivalent to `lambda2`.

Answer (score 6):

By putting the expression in the return type, you permit the compiler to invoke SFINAE. This means that if `id == 10` is not a legal expression after template substitution, then a compile error will not result. This permits `is_detected` to determine if that's a legal expression or not and therefore return a value based on that determination.

But SFINAE only works on the function's *signature*. And for the second case, the signature is `decltype(auto)`. SFINAE cannot reach into the function to pull the return expression into the signature. Therefore, if you try to instantiate this function with a type for which `id == 10` is not legal, this will only be caught when the function is instantiated. And by then, it's too late for SFINAE to protect you.

`decltype(auto)` is not identical to `decltype(expression)`. They're similar, but not identical.

Comment: The motivation -- not requiring compilers to compile the template function body just to determine which overload to select -- might be worth mentioning.